# $http.delete in angular2 not responding

Tags: angular2-http

i am building an application in angular2, there are some issues when i am using the $http.delete(for deleting value from rest API) with observable response is always an error, which states that "status:0, url:null". But i am able to perform the delete operation when i am using the $http.post with observable.
I have created REST API in cakePHP3 and i am checking  "if ($this->request->is('delete') || $this->request->is('post'))" in the Rest API function can anyone answer why this is happening.